# Magic wand tool through javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I am going to start working on a new project that requires me to crop images based on poly selection. The challenge is to allow the front end user to be able to quickly select an area in an image and then crop it. To make the process easier for the user I am thinking to provide some functionality similar to magic-wand tool in photoshop.

I found this library - https://github.com/Tamersoul/magic-wand-js

This works fine, but only let me select the area once.

My question is, is it possible to add features of multiple selections and remove a selection from the area already selected.

Check this demo fiddle to see what I am referring to - jsfiddle(dot)net/Tamersoul/dr7Dw/

Comment: Might be easier to start with an image editor that has already been written.  See this example on MDN Demo Studio called [MiniPaint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/minipaint).  Includes image cropping and magic wand tools.

Comment: "Happiness does not come from doing easy work but from the afterglow of satisfaction that comes after the achievement of a difficult task that demanded our best." Theodore Isaac Rubin

Answer (score 8):

[github.com Magic-Wand-js](https://github.com/Tamersoul/magic-wand-js)

[jsbin.com Demo](http://jsbin.com/jibiro/4/edit)

```js
$(function() {
  var colorThreshold = 15,
      blurRadius = 5,
      simplifyTolerant = 0,
      simplifyCount = 30,
      hatchLength = 4,
      hatchOffset = 0,
      imageInfo = null,
      cacheInd = null,
      cacheInds = [],      
      downPoint = null,
      mask = null,
      masks = [],
      allowDraw = false,
      currentThreshold = colorThreshold;

  $('#upload').on('change', function () {
    var inp = this;
    if (inp.files && inp.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var img = $('#test');
        img.attr('src', e.target.result);
        
        img.on('load', function() {
          resetCache();
          var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
          imageInfo = {
            width: img.width(),
            height: img.height(),
            context: canvas.getContext("2d")
          };          
          canvas.width = imageInfo.width;
          canvas.height = imageInfo.height;
          var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
              tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
          tempCanvas.width = imageInfo.width;
          tempCanvas.height = imageInfo.height;
          tempCtx.drawImage(img[0], 0, 0);
          imageInfo.data = tempCtx.getImageData(0, 0, imageInfo.width, imageInfo.height).data;
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(inp.files[0]);
    }
  });

  $('#blur').on('change keyup', function () {
    blurRadius = Number($(this).val()) || 0;
    magic();
  });

  $('#threshold').on('change keyup', function () {
    currentThreshold = Number($(this).val()) || 0;
    magic();
  });

  $('#canvas').on('click', function (e) {
    var p = $(e.target).offset(),
        x = Math.round((e.clientX || e.pageX) - p.left),
        y = Math.round((e.clientY || e.pageY) - p.top);    
    downPoint = { x: x, y: y };    
    magic();
  });

  var magic = function () {
    if (imageInfo) {
      var image = {
        data: imageInfo.data,
        width: imageInfo.width,
        height: imageInfo.height,
        bytes: 4
      };
      mask = MagicWand.floodFill(image, downPoint.x, downPoint.y, currentThreshold);
      mask = MagicWand.gaussBlurOnlyBorder(mask, blurRadius);
      masks.push(mask);
      cacheInds.push(MagicWand.getBorderIndices(mask));
      drawBorder(true);
    }
  };
  
  var drawBorder = function () {
    if (masks.length) {

      var x, y, k, i, j, m,
          w = imageInfo.width,
          h = imageInfo.height,
          ctx = imageInfo.context,
          imgData = ctx.createImageData(w, h),
          res = imgData.data;
      
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      
      for (m = 0; m < masks.length; m++) {
        
        cacheInd = cacheInds[m];
        
        for (j = 0; j < cacheInd.length; j++) {
          i = cacheInd[j];
          x = i % w; // calc x by index
          y = (i - x) / w; // calc y by index
          k = (y * w + x) * 4; 
          if ((x + y + hatchOffset) % (hatchLength * 2) < hatchLength) { 
            // detect hatch color 
            res[k + 3] = 255; // black, change only alpha
          } else {
            res[k] = 255; // white
            res[k + 1] = 255;
            res[k + 2] = 255;
            res[k + 3] = 255;
          }
        }
      }
      ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    }
  };

  setInterval(function () {
    hatchOffset = (hatchOffset + 1) % (hatchLength * 2);
    drawBorder();
  }, 100);
  
  $('#trace').on('click', function () {
    var ctx = imageInfo.context;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, imageInfo.width, imageInfo.height);
    for (var m = 0; m < masks.length; m++) {
      // draw contours
      var i, j, ps, cs = MagicWand.traceContours(masks[m]);
      cs = MagicWand.simplifyContours(cs, simplifyTolerant, simplifyCount);
      //inner
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        if (cs[i].inner) {
          ps = cs[i].points;
          ctx.moveTo(ps[0].x, ps[0].y);
          for (j = 1; j < ps.length; j++) {
            ctx.lineTo(ps[j].x, ps[j].y);
          }
        }
      }
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.stroke();
      //outer
      ctx.beginPath();
      for (i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        if (!cs[i].inner) {
          ps = cs[i].points;
          ctx.moveTo(ps[0].x, ps[0].y);
          for (j = 1; j < ps.length; j++) {
            ctx.lineTo(ps[j].x, ps[j].y);
          }
        }
      }
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      ctx.stroke(); 
    }
    resetCache();
  });
    
  var resetCache = function () {
    mask = null;
    masks = [];
    cacheInds = [];
  };
  
});
```

```css
#display * {
  cursor: crosshair;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/magic-wand-js@1.0.0/js/magic-wand.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="controls">
      <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
      <p>Blur radius
        <input value="5" id="blur" type="number"/>
      </p>
      <p>Threshold
        <input value="15" id="threshold" type="number"/>
      </p>
      <button id="trace">Trace</button>
    </div>
    <div id="display">      
      <img id="test"/>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this was of great help. Can you please tell if we select multiple areas and then want to undo the last selection, how that can be achieve?

Comment: This demo doesn't seem to work anymore (2022).  Clicking does nothing, clicking trace does nothing

Comment: Fixed (CDN URL updated) @OGSean